# I am trying to display data using fetch api but It doesn't display anything

Tags: javascript

```
 window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
     let dTitle = document.getElementById('display');
     let dDescription = document.getElementById('description');
     const api = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=520bf969179e416aa2c3608591647a76';
     fetch(api).then(response=>{
       return response.json();
     })
     .then(data=>{
       console.log(data);
       const{title,description}=data.articles;
       //set dom elements 
       dTitle.textContent=data.title;
       dDescription.textContent=data.description;
    })
});
```

`dTitle`, `dDescription` is not displayed in html tag. 
I am new to JavaScript. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `innerText` property. As using `innerHTML` is susceptible to XSS attacks

```
dTitle.innerText = title;
dDescription.innerText = description;
```

```js
    window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
                 let dTitle = document.getElementById('display');
                 let dDescription = document.getElementById('description');
                 const api = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=520bf969179e416aa2c3608591647a76';
                 fetch(api).then(response=>{
                   return response.json();
                 })
                 .then(data=>{
                   console.log(data);
                   const{title,description} = data.articles[0];
                   //set dom elements 
                   dTitle.innerText = title;
                   dDescription.innerText= description;
               })
        });
```

```html
<h2 id="display"></h2>

<p id="description"></p>
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `textContent`? Using `innerHTML` makes it susceptible to XSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
  dTitle.innerHTML = data.articles[0].title;
  dDescription.innerHTML = data.articles[0].description
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let dTitle = document.getElementById('display');
  let dDescription = document.getElementById('description');
  const api = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=520bf969179e416aa2c3608591647a76';
  fetch(api).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {

      //set dom elements 
      dTitle.innerHTML = data.articles[0].title;
      dDescription.innerHTML = data.articles[0].description;
    })
});
```

```html
<h3 id="display">
</h3>
<p id="description">
</p>
```

Comment: @Monika if you think it useful, exact solution you want , accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You actually trying to destructure title and description from an array (data.articles). This cannot be done.

You should iterate through the array and then append the text nodes.

Change your code to this

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const results = document.getElementById("results");
  const api =
    "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=520bf969179e416aa2c3608591647a76";
  fetch(api)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(({ articles }) => {
      articles.forEach(article => {
        const { title, description } = article;

        //set dom elements

        const articleElement = document.createElement("article");
        const title_node = document.createTextNode(title);
        const title_element = document.createElement("P");
        title_element.classList.add("display");

        const description_node = document.createTextNode(description);
        const description_element = document.createElement("P");
        description_element.classList.add("description");

        title_element.appendChild(title_node);
        description_element.appendChild(description_node);

        articleElement.appendChild(title_element);
        articleElement.appendChild(description_element);
        results.appendChild(articleElement);
      });
    });
});
```

and your HTML

```
<div id="results"></div>
```